# Rails-API only app testing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a rails-api only (v 5) application.  I'm attempting to run my controller tests and they are all giving me the same error message and I have no idea what is causing it.

Error:
StoresControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
RuntimeError: Invalid option key: raise_on_unfiltered_parameters=
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    app/controllers/stores_controller.rb:1:in`'
    test/controllers/stores_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in '

test "should get index" do
    get stores_url, as: :json
    assert_response :success
  end

My authentication is completely disabled.

If I run curl I don't get any error's.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you edited your application.rb adding the `raise_on_unfiltered_parameters ` option?

Comment: No I have not added raise_on_unfiltered_parameters to my application.rb.  However the following is set in my new_framework_defaults.rb
Rails.application.config.action_controller.raise_on_unfiltered_parameters = true

Setting this value to false doesn't change anything.

Comment: I just made another discovery.  When I restart my app server then run a curl command I always get the same error on the first request, but then after that it seems to work fine.  However, the minitests always fail with the error.

Comment: {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"#\u003cRuntimeError: Invalid option key: raise_on_u
nfiltered_parameters=\u003e","traces":{"Application Trace":[{"id":19,"trace":"app/controllers/application_cont
roller.rb:1:in `\u003ctop (required)\u003e'"},{"id":33,"trace":"app/controllers/products_controller.rb:1:in `\
u003ctop (required)\u003e'"}]

Comment: So it looks like the the following line in initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb needs to be commented out and not set to false.  This fixes the issue.  Thanks.

Rails.application.config.action_controller.raise_on_unfiltered_parameters = true

Comment: Bear in mind that configuration is no longer available in Rails 5.1, if you're planning to upgrade the Rails version, maybe that would also work and give you an error less.